# Is WebRTC TURN bandwith usage the same as STUN?

Tags: webrtc, twilio, stun, turn

I'm implementing HD screen sharing so minimizing bandwidth usage is very important. In the first scenerio, all clients are connected to a single client directly using stun (client a connects to client b, client a connects to client c, clients a connects to client d). In that case the user has to transmit his screen to 3 clients separately.

My question is, when TURN is used, is it the same? Or does client A connect to the turn server, and then the turn server routes that data to client b, c, and d, thus saving client a bandwidth because he only has to send the data to the TURN server? Or is it the same amount of bandwidth used?

I'm specifically asking in the use case of Twilio's WebRTC Video, so I hope the information applies there as well.

Comment: no https://youtu.be/p2HzZkd2A40?t=1209

Comment: TURN just changes the route the bits take leaving your machine. It's still 1-1 and the same amount of bits. You want an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/).

Comment: All TURN servers have a configuration setting to throttle the bitrate of any stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As the comments have been saying, there is a stream per user. If you connect to all the other users in the conversation by TURN, then that is separate streams going through the TURN server and will incur bandwidth for each user.

There is a possibility that you might not need TURN between all users, so a user may be sending data to one peer via STUN and another via TURN.

Finally, you can control this down to one stream using an SFU, as jib said. Within Twilio this would be achieved using the [Group Rooms API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#code-create-a-group-room) (which can also be used to record chats).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I misunderstood TURN jib's and your comment cleared it up. So if I understand what you're saying correctly, simply changing the room type to 'group' during room creation will utilize an 'SFU' and result in the user's stream just going out once, to the SFU, and then out to all the clients, regardless of the number of clients?